# Solve to find $y(x)$ of the $\frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }y^n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation to find the $y$ as a function to respect $x$ without $n$ $$\frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }y^n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n=0$$

Comment: HINT: The summations are geometric series.

Comment: I think this must be missing an extra condition, like $|x| < 1$ and $|y| < 1$.  =)

Comment: @Jose: I think that they’re implicit in the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $|x| < 1$ and $|y| < 1$, the two geometric series simplify to:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1 - y}} = \frac{1}{1 - x}.$$

Consequently:

$$(1 - x)(1 - y) = 1.$$

Solving for $y$ in terms of $x$, you get:

$$1 - y = \frac{1}{1 - x}$$

which implies that

$$y(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{1 - x} = \frac{x}{x - 1}.$$

Note that $|y(x)| < 1$, so that $|x/(x - 1)| < 1$.  This implies that:

$$|x| < |x - 1|,$$

which further implies that

$$x^2 < (x - 1)^2 = x^2 - 2x + 1.$$

Consequently,

$$x < \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: check when x=0.7

Comment: @Ehegh, you must also have: $|y(x)| = |x/(x - 1)| < 1$.

Comment: check the solution when x=0.7 and then tell me.

Comment: @Ehegh, when $x = 0.7$, $|y(x)| = |(0.7)/(0.7 - 1)| = 7/3 > 1$.

Comment: @Ehegh, so you need to determine which values of $x$ satisfy $|x/(x - 1)| < 1$.

Comment: @Ehegh, when $x = 0.7$, the geometric series involving $y = x/(x - 1)$ will not converge.  Hence the condition $x < 1/2$, which I have added to my answer.

Comment: ok, I have seen that.